# Function to display html code rather than display elements in browser using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to have the `innerHTML` of my `div` element to contain some HTML code, rather than displaying the expected result of that html as the browser normally would. How do I do this using Javascript?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With normal JavaScript:

```
var div = document.getElementById('foo');
while (div.firstChild) {
  div.removeChild(div.firstChild);
}
div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(html));
```

With jQuery:

```
$('#foo').text(html);
```